# C - Tricky Switch Case working .. !

Tags: c, switch-statement, case-statement

Folks,

Recently started learning C.
Stuck at a point. Its about working of switch-case statement.

Here's the code :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
        int i=4;
        switch(i) {

                default :       
                        printf("%s","Default");
                case 0:         
                        printf("%s","Case 0");
                case 1:         
                        printf("%s","Case 1");
                case 2:         
                        printf("%s","Case 2");

        return 0;
        }
 }
```

I personally think, "`Default`" should be printed, as it doesn't match with any of case value.
But when I run the code in Turbo C, what I observed was this :

```
Default
Case 0
Case 1
Case 2
```

Even same was observed here : http://www.ideone.com/pFh1d

What is the problem ? It is the compiler problem or any mistake in my code ?

---

EDIT :

**PS : What wrong does it make if at all I have to write default case first. Any harm ?**

**But once the compiler knows that it has to execute the default statement, why we need to put a break statement after the statements of default case ?**

Comment: Where's your break; statement?

Comment: Does it expect a break for each case statement ?

Comment: It doesn't but it will execute all the cases following the matched one, until it moves out  or finds the break

Comment: It doesn't "expect" anything. It does what you ask it to do. With `break` it will do one thing, without `break` it will do another thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The switch statement will jump to the appropriate `case` or `default` and then the code will continue until the next `break` statement.

As your code has no `break` it will start off at the `default:` and simply continue through all the following statements. This can sometimes be a useful trick when programming similar conditions, but generally the lack of break statements will cause confusion.

Also the final `return` is in the wrong place it should be after the switch statement.

Amend as follows.

```
        int i=4;
        switch(i) {

                default :       
                        printf("%s","Default");
                        break;
                case 0:         
                        printf("%s","Case 0");
                        break;
                case 1:         
                        printf("%s","Case 1");
                        break;
                case 2:         
                        printf("%s","Case 2");
                        break;

        }
        return 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

> But once the compiler knows that it has to execute the default statement, why we need to put a break statement after the statements of default case ?

Because that's the way the language works. The language's standard states that the execution should continue from the matching case-label. You might be wondering why the compiler does not add the `break` statements automatically, after each `case`. Well, if it did, we would not be able to do this:

```
switch(x){
case 1:
case 2:
case 3:
 // do something
 break;
case 4:
 // do something else
 break;
default:;
}
```

If the compiler added a `break` after each case, we'd have to rewrite the above code as follows:

```
  switch(x){
case 1:
 // do something
case 2:
 // do the same thing
case 3:
 // do the same thing
case 4:
 // do something else
default:
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It matched with defaule so Default and then due to absent of `break;` all the case executed

make it as follows to get your expected result

```
 default :       
                        printf("%s","Default"); break;
                case 0:         
                        printf("%s","Case 0");break;
                case 1:         
                        printf("%s","Case 1");break;
                case 2:         
                        printf("%s","Case 2");break;
```

Comment: But once the compiler knows that it has to execute the default statement, why we need to put a break statement after the statements of default case ?

Comment: @herbalessence Check out the switch case example with explanation there. http://visualcplus.blogspot.com/2006/03/lesson-12-switch-case-break-and.html

Comment: @Herbalessence - You don't have to put a break in the `default` section if you put it **last**. That is the most common place to put it.

Comment: @herbalessence: There's no such thing as "default statement". The `default:` label is an *entry point*. That's the only thing it defines: an entry point into the long compound statement. It is just a  point, not tied to any specific statements. The control jumps to that point and continues to execute from there. I.e. `switch/case/default` construct is just a form of `goto`.

Answer (score 1):

The body of `switch` statement in C language is *one single continuous compound statement* with several entry points. Each `case/default` label is an *entry point*. You can enter that compound statement at any entry point, and it will continue to execute all the way to the end (unless another jump statement intervenes, of course). In other words, `case` labels in `switch` work the same way `goto` labels do. The `default` label is not in any way different from `case` labels in this respect.

This is exactly what you observe in your experiment. The statement in your `switch` looks as follows

```
{
  printf("%s","Default");
  printf("%s","Case 0");
  printf("%s","Case 1");
  printf("%s","Case 2");
  return 0;
}
```

You enter this statement through your `default:` label at the very beginning. Since you do not alter the control flow after entering the body of your `switch` (aside from probably misplaced final `return`), all four `printf`s get a change to "fire".

The meaning of your question that begins with "But once the compiler knows that it has to execute the default statement..." is not clear to me. The functionality of `switch/case` construct in C is as I described above. That's what the "compiler knows". You, on the other hand, seem to follow some completely unfounded self-invented misconceptions about what `switch/case` does and for some reason expect the compiler to follow the same misconceptions. I'd say that you need to read a book on C language basics instead of trying to guess what various language elements do.

There's nothing wrong with making the `default` case first. Considering what I said above, in some situations the ordering of the labels inside the statement *matters*. When it matters, you have to arrange them in accordance with your intent. If you need your `default` case to be the first, make it first. If you don't need it (or it makes no difference) you can put it last or wherever else you want to put it.

Answer (score 1):

According to standards programmer has to place break manually after each case, even though it is a default case. 
If programmer is not place break means it will execute all the cases which is at and below to that case.
Where standards call this type of switch programming as FALL THROUGH condition within the switch.