# Confusing switch statement behaviour

Tags: c++

I saw this code and I expected the output to be 6, but I got 17.

```
int x = 3;
switch (x)
{
  case 1: { x += x; }
  case 3: { x += x; }
  case 5: { x += x; }
  default: { x += 5; }
}
std::cout << x;
```

Why does `x` become 17? Shouldn't it become 6 by selecting the case 3 and exiting the switch statement?

Even if it would go through the default case after the case 3, `x` would only be 11. The only way I see that `x` would become 17 is by going through case (1 & 3) or (3 & 5) + the default case. I don't see why it would work like that though.

Any direction on what's happening step-by-step would be great!

Comment: You forgot `break`

Comment: @GauravSehgal Arrgh! Well, that's the solution right there :D

Comment: This is why coding standard matters: some C++ coding standard does not allow write one-line code like this, and thus makes it easier to find `break` is forgot.

Comment: Downvoter, how is this a bad question?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776253/c-tricky-switch-case-working

Comment: @GauravSehgal I don't believe that this is a duplicate. That is a question for the language C. For all I could know, C switch statement could work a lot differently than in C++.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you don't use `break` in your `switch` case statement, the code doesn't stop at the matching case evaluation but proceeds executing all the other case statements below until a `break` is found or when the `switch` statement completes.

In this example the first matching case is executed for `x == 3` and then it proceeds executing all of the below statements, leading to `17` as a result.

**You can read more about the reasons for this here**:

- [Why was the switch statement designed to need a break?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252489/why-was-the-switch-statement-designed-to-need-a-break#252733)

Answer (score 5):

You forgot about `break;` instruction. When you switch-case c++ runs from first case that is true up to break. So your code goes like this:

```
int x = 3;
switch (x)
{
  case 1: { x += x; } // ignored
  case 3: { x += x; } // goes in
  case 5: { x += x; } // still executes, because of no break
  default: { x += 5; } // still executes, because of no break
}
std::cout << x;
```

Answer (score 3):

Cases in switch statements fall through to the next one, unless you add a `break`. I.e., when you give it `3`, it runs case 3, falls through to case `5`, and then falls through to the default case.

To avoid this, add `break;` at the end of your cases:

```
int x = 3;
switch (x)
{
  case 1: { x += x; break; }
  case 3: { x += x; break; }
  case 5: { x += x; break; }
  default: { x += 5; break; }
}
std::cout << x;
```

### See also

- [C++ Syntax: `switch`](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Companion/cxx_crib/switch.html)

Answer (score 1):

In `c` and `c++` `switch` statement behaves like civilized `goto` statement. Every `case` is kind of label and execution goes to corresponding label and then go through other cases after. So you have to use `break` after every `case` if you don't want other cases executed after one.